# Flex network logger is not working after updated iOS14

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, ios14

After iOS 14 have been updated, My friend complained about Flex Tool network logging is not working.
I am sharing the solution for community:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your pod file in your project and inject that :

```
pod 'FLEX', :git => 'https://github.com/FLEXTool/FLEX', :configurations => ['Debug']
```